# When organizing an AngularJS app, should your modules all have the same name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, organization

When organizing a alrger Angular project, should your modules have the same name? I've seen examples of both all over the place.

Given a structure like this:

```
root-app-folder
├── index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── main.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── directives
│   │   └── myDirective.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── filters
│   │   └── myFilter.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── services
│   │   └── myService.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── vendor
│   │   ├── angular.js
│   │   ├── angular.min.js
│   │   ├── es5-shim.min.js
│   │   └── json3.min.js
│   └── app.js
├── styles
│   └── ...
└── views
    ├── main.html
    └── ...
```

Would you typically have each of your files start with `angular.module('appName')...` or have them be unique, such as `angular.module('thisModuleName)...` ?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read [**johnpapa's guide**](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

Comment: @developer033 Thanks! That's one heck of a read, very in depth.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical project you would only work with a single module. Generally the module would be declared in the `app.js` file with the array syntax:

```
angular.module('app', ['dep1', 'dep2'])
```

Where `dep1` and `dep2` are any dependencies your module needs. Then in any other file - eg a controller - you merely link it to the `app` module like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller(...) // no dependency array
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this advice differs from the angularjs tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) -- "Each feature/section should declare its own module and all related entities should register themselves on that module."

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS comes with a built-in dependency injection mechanism. You can divide your application into multiple different types of components which AngularJS can inject into each other. Modularizing your application makes it easier to reuse, configure and test the components in your application.

AngularJS contains the following core types of objects and components:

- Value
- Factory
- Service
- Provider
- Constant

These core types can be injected into each other using AngularJS dependency injection mechanism. Throughout the rest of this text I will explain how to define and inject these components into each other.

Comment: Ramin, I am aware of the Angular dependency injection and component model. I am however, wondering if using a single module name is the ideal way to organize your app, vs multiple module names that need to be injected.

Comment: Dear Douglas, This completely depends on your project scale and requirements. If your project will be so large, Absolutely you must divide the project into smaller fragments and handle their dependencies and so on. But generally in common and medium scale projects it's better to have the same module in the whole project.